# How do I add variables to existing ones when a form is submitted i.e. 10 + 1

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post

I'm trying to make a slot machine in php. I know a little bit about session variables and I'm currently stuck.

The slot machine gives you 10 points each time a new player comes to the page. when you play the machine, you get points based off of what you get.

I'm trying to figure out how to add or subtract from the initial 10 points when the player hits the form button.

What I'm looking to do is keep score until someone refreshes the page and the session variable is unset.

Comment: Please show us your code first.

Comment: `$_SESSION['points']++;` or `$_SESSION['points']--;`  There is not one real questionmark in your question ;-)

Comment: isnt it better to use javascript for this?

Comment: @Debet Wah 100 Points, but how should someone explain this in a comment. `slot machine in php` sounds so strange to me :))

Comment: Little hint on this `each time a new player comes to the page` normally each player/user get his own session...

Comment: And if a player `hits the form button` then `someone refreshes the page`...

Comment: If you really want someone to help you. Get clear what you want, what you want to use for what (PHP,JS,AJAX) , try it on your own, and if you get stuck, paste code here and ask for help. someone will help then....